# Is Twilio a SMS Aggregator or a SMS Software Service Provider?

Tags: twilio

Our app currently uses Vibe for SMS Aggregation and we have started considering transferring our application to Twilio.

Does anyone know if Twilio is a SMS Aggregator or if, instead, they provide their services by interfacing with an aggregator? If so, which aggregator do they use?

I haven't found any detailed information with a google search or from Twilio's website.

thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess it depends on the definition of SMS Aggregator. Twillio and Sinch have carrier partners for SMS in different regions I would think.  Depends what region you operate in as to who routes the SMS, that's how it would work for standard single SMS.  I work for Sinch and they offer SMS services. https://www.sinch.com/products/apis/messaging/sms/#block-pricing-and-usps-v2-11

Comment: thanks for replying! I'm defining sms aggregator as "a service that interfaces directly with carriers" and 'not sms aggregator' as "a service that interfaces with an sms aggregator to provide their services" 

I'm based in the US. Do you know if Sinch and/or Twilio does sms aggregation for carriers in the US?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply I never had this thread monitored.   ForSinch https://www.sinch.com/products/apis/messaging/sms/ you can see the price for sending SMS in US and what carriers are used.   Scroll down to pricing, choose "United States of America", the currency you want to use, click "operator details" and a list of suppliers will show with associated rates.